# Vertical-align is not working in safari and chrome

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="commentator grid_3">
    <img src="http://img.gawkerassets.com/img/183mxcnx46v2cjpg/avt-large.jpg" alt="commentator">
    <span class="commentator-name"><a href="#">Joshua</a></span>
</div>
```

So I set commentator-name vertical-align to Top.It works in firefox but not in chrome and safari.
Can someone help me out??I dont want to use position absolute when I have a perfect choice...

Comment: what makes you think it's not working in webkit, but is in the others?

Comment: and what did you see when you checked? and what did you think you should have seen?

Comment: 1.stayed at the bottom. 2.I said above

Answer (score 16, accepted):

please add the display:inline-block to span tag.lik this:

```
.commentator-name{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

please view the [demo](http://codepen.io/airen/pen/Cedng).

Comment: I added the .commentator-name to a.tag and it worked.I dont understand why should we change it to block element since vertical-align works on img.tag which is inline-element

Comment: OK,I think I find out the answer

Comment: you can use the flexbox module and you can use the display: table.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, but img should be an inline-block too, because it's rectangular and has a defined width/height, so it's blocky. and inline because it floats around with your text. => inline-block.

Comment: Demo does not work for me in chrome -- something changed?

Answer (score 0):

Vertical line image with in div  works on Chrome and Safari. The code is:

```
<div class="image-wrap">
    <img src="xyz.png"/>
</div>
```

and

```
.image-wrap {
    display:table-cell;
    width:400px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```