# Vertically Center align text - works in chrome, but not on safari

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please see this Jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/cxhm681x/

Please check this on Chrome and Safari.

I want to vertically centre align OrderNo and Order Name.
This works fine in Chrome, but on Safari, OrderNo is aligned to the top.

Here's the code:

```
<body style="height:100%;">
<div style="width:100%; height:100%; ">

<div  style="height:0%; background-color: black;display: flex;align-items: center;">    
    <div style="width:20%;">
    <label id="theNofNx" style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:small;margin-left:5px;">Order No</label>
    </div>
    <div style="width:80%;align-items:center;text-align:center;margin: 0 auto;">
      <a href="#" target="_blank" style="color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration:none;">Order Name</a>
    </div>
    <div style="width:20%;"><label id="theNofNx" style="color: #FFFFFF;font-size:small;margin-right:5px;text-align:right;"></label></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

How do i make this work for Safari as well (works in chrome)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertical-align is not working in safari and chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17312521/vertical-align-is-not-working-in-safari-and-chrome)

Comment: This code outputs text all on one line. Are you sure this is working in Chrome? Please update the question with code that fits what you're describing

Comment: @TylerH > Please take a look in Safari - you can see the difference.

Comment: @Jasper You said the vertical alignment "works fine in Chrome" but it's not aligned vertically at all in Chrome, so it "not working" in Safari isn't what needs clarifying at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go with below css class for your div

```
<style>
.div_parent
{
  display:table;
  height:50px;
  background-color: black;
  text-align:center;
}
.div_child
{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  font-size:small;
  margin-left:5px;
  width:20%;
}
</style>

<body>
<div style="width:100%; height:100%; ">
<div class="div_parent">    
    <div class="div_child">
    <label id="theNofNx">Order No</label>
    </div>
    <div class="div_child">
      <a href="#" target="_blank" style="color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration:none;">Order Name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="div_child"><label id="theNofNx" style="color: #FFFFFF;font-size:small;margin-right:5px;text-align:right;"></label></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Pratham the idea of using display:table-cell worked.

Answer (score -2):

try the display:table method and the code should be something like this

```
  <div style="width:100%; height:100%; ">

        <div style="height:0%; background-color: black;display: flex;align-items: center;">
            <div style="width:20%;display:table;">
                <label id="theNofNx" style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:small;margin-left:5px;display: table-cell;vertical-align:middle;">Order No</label>
            </div>
            <div style="width:80%;display: table;">
                <a href="#" target="_blank" style="color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration:none;display: table-cell;vertical-align:middle;">Order Name</a>
            </div>
            <div style="width:20%;display: table;">
                <label id="theNofNx" style="color: #FFFFFF;font-size:small;margin-right:5px;text-align:right;display: table-cell;vertical-align:middle;"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Hope this helps

Take care and happy coding

Comment: This doesn't change any vertical alignment; it just moves Order Name to the left.